# python flask: pass response from a FB API call to back-end

Tags: javascript, python, facebook

I'm integrating the [Facebook SDK for JavaScript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) into my Python Flask web application. I want the ability to access a logged in user's Facebook *id* server-side.

My current approach is to build a form containing a hidden input which stores the id and submit it when the user logs in:

```
<script>
  function sendToBackEnd(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
      if (response.status == 'connected'){
        $form = $('<form>', {'action': '/process_form', 'method': 'POST'}).appendTO('body');
        FB.api('/me', function(response){
          $('<input>', {'class': 'hidden', 'name': 'FB_id', 'value': response.id}).appendTo($form);
        });
      }
    });
  }
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="sendToBackEnd"></div>
```

Then store that id in the flask `session` object:

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process():
    session['FB_id'] = request.form['FB_id']
    print("User's Facebook id now accessible across all routes server-side!")
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Is there a better approach here or is submitting a hidden form the only way to pass this data from client to server-side?

Just a thought... I noticed there's a parameter in the [FB.init()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.10) method called `cookie` which is a described as, "Inidcates whether a cookie is created for the session. If enabled, it can be accessed by server-side code." I'm pretty sure the flask session object can't be modified client-side (rightfully so), but maybe this separate cookie can be assessed server-side in my python code?

Comment: Just found this [Facebook SDK for Python library](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which may be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use a GET or POST request to the Flask app after I login / logout. Creating the form was totally unnecessary and overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user's fb_id as a session cookie and access it server-side. This can be done by `fb_id = request.cookies.get('COOKIE_NAME')`

Comment: I've tried doing a `print(request.cookies)` and I'm only seeing the flask session cookie

Comment: What cookies have you created on the client side? If I cookie has been successfully created on the client side at the point a request is sent to the server, you will be able to access it using request.cookies.get

Comment: I see the flask session cookie and Facebook creates about a dozen different cookies. None of the FB cookies are assessable via request.cookies which is odd